# Fulltext Search for Custom Type's TextField/RichWidget

Tags: plone, archetypes

Typing keyword in search box, say `日光` (Chinese words), I can see the live search result hinting the target items. It works well for types of Products.ATContentTypes (NewsItem, Page), but fails to find the same keyword for items of my custom type. Here is the partial code for the type:

```python
atapi.TextField(
    'history',
    storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
    default_output_type='text/x-html-safe',
    widget=atapi.RichWidget(
        label=_(u"Establishment History"),
        description=_(u"Enter Establishment History."),
        rows = 20,
    ),
),
```

I do try add `searchable=1,` to the field, and re-catalog, but still no working. What am I missing?

Comment: make sure to add ``searchable=True`` to the field and not to the widget. restart the zope instance. you might also need to update the schema in archetypes_tool for existing objects

Comment: I do add `searchable=True` to the field, and install the package in a fresh new Plone instance. Also archetypes_tool update tried. The issue remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add the keyword searchable=True to your definition.

```python
atapi.TextField(
    'history',
    searchable=True,
    storage=atapi.AnnotationStorage(),
    default_output_type='text/x-html-safe',
    widget=atapi.RichWidget(
        label=_(u"Establishment History"),
        description=_(u"Enter Establishment History."),
        rows = 20,
    ),
),
```